# Default value used for Kernel density SAS

Tags: sas, kernel-density, sgplot

I'm using SAS to plot an histogram with the Kernel density. In the documentation, it is specified that we can choose the parameter c: "the standardized bandwidth for a number that is greater than 0 and less than or equal to 100." But I cannot find the default value used to create the following plot.

Does someone have an idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SGPLOT minimizes the Asymptotic Mean Integrated Square Error (AMISE) for the kernel density function. According to `PROC UNIVARIATE`, which also can do KDE:

> By default, the procedure uses the AMISE method to compute kernel density estimates.
>
> [PROC UNIVARIATE documentation](https://go.documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=procstat&docsetTarget=procstat_univariate_syntax09.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#procstat.univariate.hist_kernel)

We can confirm that they both have the same default by comparing the output.

```
proc univariate data=sashelp.cars;
    var horsepower;
    histogram / kernel;
run;
```

In the log, we find:

```
NOTE: The normal kernel estimate for c=0.7852 has a bandwidth of 21.035 and an AMISE of 392E-7.
```

Let's plot them together and compare the values.

```
proc sgplot data=sashelp.cars;  
   density horsepower/TYPE=KERNEL;  
   density horsepower/TYPE=KERNEL(c=0.7852);
   ods output sgplot;
run;

data diff;
    set sgplot;
    abs_diff = abs(KERNEL_Horsepower____Y - KERNEL_Horsepower_C_0_7852____Y);
run;

proc univariate data=diff;
    var abs_diff;
run;
```

[image]

The average difference between all points plotted is 1.65x10^-9, with the overall largest being 6.76x10^-9. This is, essentially, zero. The reason for the differences is that the c-value given to the user in the log is lower precision than the one calculated by `proc sgplot`. You can get a higher precision estimate with the `outkernel=` option in `proc univariate` as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot Stu Sztukowski, it is all very clear ! :)

Comment: Glad it helped! They should include this documentation with sgplot as well. I'll email tech support that feedback.